# Javascript when true, var is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have the following code block for testing:

```
var readyToGo = false;

readyToGo = true;

console.log(readyToGo); // reads "true" in console

if(readyToGO === false){ // also tried readyToGO == false (that fails too)
  console.log('not ready');
  return false;  
} else {
  alert("true, and we're done!");
}
```

The problem is, the console reads:

```
true
ReferenceError: readyToGO is not defined
```

Why is there a reference error? What am I missing?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sa3Lqr7u/)

Comment: It means that you are not ready to go: you need to install some good IDE that would highlight you undefined variables :)

Comment: your variable in if condition is not readyToGo. Correct it and try again

Comment: What a *&&^% I am !! schoolboy error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive, you have an uppercase O in `readyToGO`, change to:

```
if(readyToGo === false){
//         ^ use lowercase o not O
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sa3Lqr7u/1/)

Comment: And that's why you use JsHint/Lint/other static analyzer, so you never have to turn to SO for typos :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is named `readyToGo` and not `readyToGO`. Change your check to this:

```
if(readyToGo === false){ // also tried readyToGO == false (that fails too)
```

Answer (score 0):

readyToGO - typo. should be readyToGo